# Marble Probability

Tags: probability

If I have 5 Blue, 6 Red, 4 Black and 3 White marbles in a bag, and am allowed to take 4 without replacement, what is the probability of;

- one from each colour
  (5/18*6/17*4/16*3/15?)
- no blue balls picked 
  (1-(5/18*4/17*3/16*2/15))?
- 2 blue and 2 white
  (5/18*4/17*3/16*2/15?)
- Will pick only Blue or Red (mainly stuck on this one, would it be 4B union 4R?)

Comment: Not sure what the last case means.  Does that mean only $RRRR,BBBB$ or does it include things like $RBBR$? (here $R=Red, B=Black$).

Comment: Note:  I think you need to check some (all?) of your early answers.  For the first, for example, you correctly compute the probability of getting $Blue, Red, Black, White$ in that exact order.  But that;s not the only way to get one of each color.

Comment: I dont believe order will matter- just how many combinations and not permutations?

Comment: @Jack Second question: It is still without replacement. Thus the denominator has to decrease. But using the converse probability is a good idea.

Comment: For the first question, I agree order should not matter.  So, you need to count all possible orders.

Comment: For the second, There are $13$ non-blue balls initially.  So the probability that the first is non-blue is $\frac {13}{18}$.  Work from there.  For the third, again you  have to consider all possible orders.

Comment: For the last, I believe it is BBBB or RRRR, not other combinations

Comment: Picking only blue or red mean neither white nor black are picked.

Comment: So the probability of only blue or red would be P(4B)*P(4R)? That is (5/18*4/17*3/16*2/15)*(6/18*5/17*4/16*3/15)?

Comment: You might select *some* red and *some* blue; just none from the white and none from the black.  (Plus, why do you think multiplying the probabilities would work, they are clearly not independent events and you don't seek the intersection.)

Answer (score 2):

Recollect: $\binom nr$ counts the ways to select $r$ from a set of $n$ items.

> one from each colour (5/18*6/17*4/16*3/15?)

That is for: one from each colour *in a certain order*. Multiply by $4!$ to account for permutations.   (Since order doesn't matter you must count all of them; above and below.)   You seek the probability for selecting one from each of the colour groups when drawing four from eighteen balls.

$$\frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom 61\binom 41\binom 31}{\binom {18}{4}}= \frac{5\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 4!}{18\cdot 17\cdot 16\cdot 15 }$$

> no blue balls picked (1-(5/18*4/17*3/16*2/15))?

I am not sure what you are trying to count here.    You want the probability for selecting four from thirteen non-blue balls when drawing four from the eighteen balls.

> 2 blue and 2 white (5/18*4/17*3/16*2/15?)

As before that is in a particular order.     You want the probability for selecting two from five blue balls and two from three white balls when drawing four from the eighteen balls.

> Will pick only Blue or Red (mainly stuck on this one, would it be 4B union 4R?)

Selecting only blue or red means that none of the four balls shall be black or white.

You want the probability for selecting four from eleven blue-or-red balls when drawing four from the eighteen balls.